# How do I ask a question like this and not get flagged?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question on SO about an intermittent issue I'm seeing and it was flagged as "off-topic". I understand the idea that something should ideally be reproducible, but as near as I can tell this is thanks to the vagaries of the web and might be caused by any number of browser inconsistencies or third party plugins. I'm fairly confident that the issue is not in our code, but of course, I can't vouch for all of the npm packages we're using. I'm wondering how or where I go about asking a question like this that may not have clear repro steps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400385/javascript-array-prototype-is-undefined

Comment: your question is missing a stack trace. Is it possible to create one?

Comment: basically... things in javascript don't just randomly happen. There's a reason that error is being thrown, a set of circumstances that if re-created, will reproduce the same problem. Without those circumstances, the question can't be answered accurately.

Comment: Without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we just have to **guess** at what your issue is and how to solve it. Questions like that usually devolve into dynamic debugging sessions with people just tossing out (sometimes good) guesses as to what the problem might be. Even when there is a solution that works for you, it's rarely helpful to others. You need to describe what steps are needed to reproduce the issue, even if it is intermittent.

Comment: Is there a forum you'd recommend for getting help producing an MCVE? The only thing I've really got is that it seems to be consistently the same set of just a few users, not all IE or Safari users.

Comment: What do those users have in common?  Plugins?  AV?  Add logging, collect stats.  We cannot help with intermitent bugs.  They're very difficult to stomp on when you are sitting right in front of the server/client nd have access to everything.  Over a text interface like this, it's imp.... very, very difficult.  Intermittent networked system bugs are the worst;(

Answer (score 15):

> I'm fairly confident that the issue is not in our code...

If this is the case, then you should be able to produce an example that doesn't make use of your code, yet still exhibits the same errors in IE 11.  That's essentially why your question is closed now; without really being able to reproduce it on a machine that's running IE 11, we can't tell if your question is accurate or if it *is* based on some dependency you've got.

Comment: The problem here is that it doesn't always happen in IE 11. It seems to be happening for only a handful of IE 11 users consistently and not the vast majority of the others. How do I go about narrowing this down, or where do I go for advice on things like this?

Comment: Honestly, narrowing it down is kind of basic debugging; find out what's different about those users' browsing/network environment, use patterns (i.e., maybe these users get to the page differently from others), etc.. That's stuff only you can do.